# Dynamic Camembert

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to create a dynamic camemebrt in which i will use an sql code to get the percentage. I have a table in which i have :

```
  Montant  |  libelle | Bureau  
|   20     |    A1    |   B1    |
|   30     |    A2    |   B2    |
|   70     |    A1    |   B2    |
|   80     |    A2    |   B1    |
```

---

In my Camembert I have a filter from which I will choose the value of the "Bureau" column :

So when I choose `B1` value I get a camember  with : 
for Bureau 1 : 20% A1 and 80% A2

And when I choose "all bureau" to get a statisitc of all bureau i get : 
For all bureau :  50% A1 and 50% a2.

I'm using this query :

```
select (sum(MONTANT) / (select  sum(MONTANT) from table1)) 
from table1 
where id_bureau= "the value of filtre" 
group by libelle;
```

It's work when I choose all bureau from the filter , but when I want to show the percentage of only one "bureau" I got a wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

You should just sum the matching values. Bureau = 'B1' is 1 if true and 0 if false.

```
 select libelle, sum(montant * (Bureau = 'B1')) / sum(Bureau)
 from table1
 group by libelle
```

gives every libelle with the parts.

Is that what you want?